# Compute module 2D Drawings (dimensions)?

Tags: hardware

I'm designing a case for the Raspberry Pi compute module case with the default PCB from Element 14 , and can't find the dimensions or 2D drawings anywhere.

Does anyone here know where to get them?

Answer (score 2):

All the compute module Gerbers are available at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/designfiles.md

I assume what you need is somewhere among the zip.

Comment: yes I took outside meassures with the gerber files and this script

https://www.wayneandlayne.com/blog/2013/04/02/script-to-query-gerber-file-outer-dimensions/

But I need more technical Dimensions :(

Comment: What is not "technical" about a gerber file? all the information about the boards shape and the location of the holes should be in there.